# What is the common term to express "your shorts are so sagging that people can almost see your butt"?

Tags: word-request

What is the common term to express "**your shorts are so sagging that people can almost see your butt**"?

My little child is wearing shorts & the rubber band of the shorts is so weak that it can not hold the shorts up.

So the shorts are a little sagging on my child butt & everyone can almost see his butt.

Can I say "**you are wearing sagging shorts with butt up**" or some common term that native people often say to express that situation.?

Comment: Just so you know for the future, the part of the pants you called 'the rubber band' is called the 'waistband'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funnily enough, you used the word yourself: **sagging** (also "low-riding").

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagging_(fashion)):

> **Sagging** is a manner of wearing trousers or jeans that sag so that the top of the trousers or jeans are significantly below the waist, sometimes revealing much of the underwear.
>
> Sagging is predominantly a male fashion. Women's wearing of low-rise jeans to reveal their G-string underwear (the "whale tail") is not generally described as sagging. A person wearing sagging trousers is sometimes called a "sagger", and in some countries this practice is known as "low-riding". It has become popular since the popularity of wearing brightly colored and patterned "boxer shorts".
>
> Sagging first peaked in popularity during the 1990s and remained popular into the mid 2000s, but it has recently made a comeback in the 2010s, with celebrities like Justin Bieber, Liam Payne, Ross Lynch, Zac Efron and more bringing back the fashion trend. Sagging in the 1990s usually focused on baggy trousers with plaid boxers, but in the 2010s sagging has become popular with skinny jeans and branded boxer-briefs.

In this usage, it's a verb that describes the action of the person wearing the pants.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps "low slung",  this tends to be a style choice by teens, to wear jeans with the waistband low perhaps showing the waistband of their underwear (but not so low that their butts show)

For a little child you would just say "Jonny, your shorts are falling down" or some similar expression. There are no specific words, you would make up your own sentence.  In many cases you would leave part of the sentence *unspoken*.  "Jonny! We can see your butt!"  (implying from the context that the reason is that the rubber is weak etc.) When talking to little children, families often develop their own expressions: "Jonny, you're wearing your falling-downers again."

For an adult you would not normally mention anything. However there is the "workman's bum" (butt-crack exposed by a fat man bending over)

So there is no "common term" but you could use a sentence like the one you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, 'You have plumber's butt.' This is a situation like you describe, where the pants are so low in the back that anybody can see the top of the bare behind of the person wearing them, especially when the person is bending over.

I don't know why plumbers are named in relation to this condition. It certainly happens with others, but maybe it's because they bend over so much as part of their job.